# dplyr over a data subset

Tags: r, dplyr

Assuming the following dataframe

```
foo = c(1, 2, 3) 
bar = c("AA", "AB", "AC")
other = c("Z","N","Z")
df = data.frame(foo,bar,other,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have a dplyr transformation running over several lines and for one of them I would like to only use a data subset.

In other words, starting from

```
 df%>%
      mutate(other=replace(other, foo > 1, "New"))
```

is it possible to convert the following code in dplyr

```
df[df$foo<3,]$bar<-sub("A", "B", df[df$foo<3,]$bar)
```

to something like this

```
mutate(df$foo<3=sub("A", "B", df$foo<3, perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: Maybe this `df %>% mutate(bar = ifelse(foo < 3, sub("A","B", bar), bar))`. It will update the `bar` value only when `foo` < 3, otherwise it will leave `bar` as it is.

Comment: yes or `dplyr::if_else` if speed is a concern

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df  %>%
  mutate(other=replace(other, foo > 1, "New"),
         bar= ifelse(foo<3,sub("A", "B", bar),bar))

#   foo bar other
# 1   1  BA     Z
# 2   2  BB   New
# 3   3  AC   New
```

Answer (score 0):

I  know this question is about `dplyr` but FYI the `data.table` syntax is similar to your attempt at using `mutate`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[foo > 1, other := 'New']
df[foo < 3, bar := sub('A', 'B', bar)]
df

#    foo bar other
# 1:   1  BA     Z
# 2:   2  BB   New
# 3:   3  AC   New

#With pipes
df %>% 
  .[foo > 1, other := 'New'] %>% 
  .[foo < 3, bar := sub('A', 'B', bar)]
```